# Yosemite with exchange server : Inbox email is not updated with the latest message

Tags: macos, email, ms-office

I have tried this on both Outlook for Mac 2011 and native Mail app on Yosemite.

The issue is all folders of email i.e Sent will be updated with the latest email but not on inbox.

I can only download the latest email if I empty the cache or re-create the account.

Comment: what is it? a gmail ? a IMAP gmail?

Comment: exchange  server